# Android: AlertDialog not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I want an Alert Dialog (a form to take some input from user) to show up when pressed back in an Activity, eg.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    showFormDialog();
}

private void showFormDialog() {
    //Preparing views
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_form, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.llid));
    //layout_root should be the name of the "top-level" layout node in the dialog_layout.xml file.
    final EditText txtFB = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtFB);

    //Building dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(layout);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            //save info where you want it
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
}
```

dialog_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtFB"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="hello type something here"/>
    </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

*I can see the showFormDialog code is executed on back press, but no AlertDialog shows up!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to call `.show()`

```
dialog.show();
```

`.show()` cause to creates an **AlertDialog** with the arguments supplied to this builder and immediately displays the dialog.

Comment: Oops... missed that !

Answer (score 1):

Just add this

```
dialog.show();
```

Creating it is not enough. You should show it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `dialog.show()` :

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```